# How to remove this Altium error?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

[image: screenshot from Altium]

I have already changed the size of region and my friends, with same design and placement, are not getting this error. What is the cause?

Comment: What error?  The more information you provide, the better the chances of getting a useful response.  I'm guessing that your problem is with some PCB layout software - you should mention what software you are using.

Comment: This appears to be a problem related to the so-called "Violation Overlay". Try this documentation: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/design-rule-checking-ad?version=18.1

Comment: Set up your [design rules](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/constraining-the-design-design-rules-ad)!

Answer (score 1):

From the attached image, I assume this is an overlapping problem in Altium Designer (green  X's error markers, you should also include this in the post, in terms of what software you are using, what the component is, and what specifically you are having trouble with).

The direct solution is to go to the top menu: `Tools` > `Reset Error Markers`.

You can also try pressing <kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd>

You might also try running a Design Rule Check (DRC), it will also remove the error markers, but seems to disable them completely until the file is re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Change your design rules to allow for tighter spacing between pads.
I can't remember the exact details right now, but you can specify the design rules to apply to that particular footprint.  It may also be an issue with solder mask rules.  In any case, the footprint by itself should not cause a DRC error.  Check your friends' design rules, or just import them.